# Is there a way to give a GitHub team privilege to read and write only to a private fork?

Tags: git, github, git-pull, git-fork

I'm a student with only the basic GitHub account. Me and three other classmates have formed a group to work with a software company representative for a university course.

The company has a private GitHub repository. In order to share their repository, they'd like it to fulfill 4 requirements:

1. Only one person should have access to their repo
2. Have a repo for the group that isn't on their repo
3. Have the ability to pull changes from a branch on their repo
4. Have the ability to push/merge our changes to their repo

I was thinking a fork of their repo would be perfect. However, since this is my first using private repos on GitHub, I was not expecting my current roadblock: I don't have permission to add collaborators to the forked project.

I am thinking of two possible solution but Im not sure if these are even possible:

1. Can the company rep create a team in their organization to give read and write access to only a forked project (and not the original project)?
2. If I have a GitHub account that allows me to create private repos, will I be able to add collaborators? (I'm thinking this won't change anything?)

Or maybe, there is a better way to go about fulfilling their requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think either of your solutions are allowed by github.

What I would do is to pull from the github repo, make a shared private repo on some hosting that allows it for free (like bitbucket) and push it to there for your collaborators to share. I think that fulfills all the requirements.

When you wish you can pull the latest from your private bitbucket repo, merge them to code from github repo and push it there. You'd just have two different remotes for your local repository.

If the company wants to work through pull requests and review your changes before merging, you could fork the company repo and push the merged changes there. From your fork you could issue pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the company has a [github organization](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations), the company can create a team that has push access and give the team access to a fork of the repo.  However, only members of their github organization can fork the repo or be in the org's teams.  This means the company would have to add you and your classmates to their github org, something they'd typically probably only do with employees.

If it's a small company that for some reason doesn't have a github organization, the company could add your classmates as collaborators on your fork.  The owner of the original repo should have the power to add anyone as a collaborator on the original repo *and* any forks of it.

But why not have your classmates make their own forks as well?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out a way. It's similar to my second solution. However, I did not have upgrade my account. All I needed to do was to create an organization and fork the private repo to the organization instead of my individual account. From there I was able to create my own teams and invite my classmates to the same forked project.